# AngularJS $http.post and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs, post

I'm using AngularJS to $http.post an object, but I also want to include some kind of data in the URL (or some other way) to specify what this object contains and where to parse it in the PHP file. Any idea how I can send a variable similar to GET into the AngularJS post so in PHP I can route the object to the correct if statement for parsing?

Here is my AngularJS code:

```
$scope.saveSchool=function(){
  var schoolData = angular.copy($scope.schoolsModal);
  $http.post('data/data.php?schoolModal=save', schoolData).error(function(){
    console.log('Did not post data to data.php');
  });
};
```

And here is my PHP code in data.php file in hopes to receive and route the object to the correct if statement for parsing and eventually saving the data.

```
if (isset($_GET["schoolModal"])) {
  if ($_GET["schoolModal"] == "save") {
   $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
   $request = json_decode($postdata);
   echo "Acknowledged";
   echo $postdata;
 }
```

}

This doesn't work, as it doesn't throw any errors or return anything (PHP). This does work, but I'm unable to route the object in the php file (i would have to create a separate php file just for this angularjs json object).

```
$scope.saveSchool=function(){
  console.log('saveSchool function initiated');
  var schoolData = angular.copy($scope.schoolsModal);
  $http.post('data/data.php', schoolData).error(function(){
    console.log('Did not post data to data.php');
  });
};
```

PHP Script that would need to be in it's own file, as I want to eventually have multiple post functions and parse the data as it's received:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
echo $postdata;
```

}

That PHP code works just fine, but i'm unable to route the data to where it needs to go. I don't want to send ALL posts to that if statement. Any ideas, I'm new to AngularJS and PHP and doing my best to pick this up.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to tag the incoming post information so I know what to do with it in PHP.

Comment: Generically, I think you need to set the HTTP host header. Have you seen this? http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example from a project I did. It only has 1 param 'status', but obviously you can add all of your params to an object like that

```
postFavorite: function(id, type, record, resource) {
  var xsrf = $.param({status: record.prop});

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: this.api_base + '/favorites/'+type+'/'+id,
    data: xsrf,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},                 
    withCredentials: true
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    if(data.success){
      console.log("Success:", data, status, headers, config);
    }
  });
},
```